# org.eclipse.swt.SWTException when trying to publish a report to JasperReports Server using the button

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver, jaspersoft-studio

I am trying to publish a Report to JasperReports Server using the button in Jaspersoft Studio but the dialog won't open.

This is the error that I see in .metadata/.log file

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 0 2016-09-09 12:38:54.508
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception during blocked modal context.
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.NullPointerException)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4491)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4406)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:138)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3794)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3433)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.block(ModalContext.java:172)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:387)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1002)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.publish.wizard.page.RUnitLocationPage.look4SelectedUnit(RUnitLocationPage.java:572)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.publish.wizard.page.RUnitLocationPage.access$24(RUnitLocationPage.java:570)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.publish.wizard.page.RUnitLocationPage$10.run(RUnitLocationPage.java:534)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3794)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3433)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.rcp.intro.Application.start(Application.java:99)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabFolder.gtk_switch_page(TabFolder.java:570)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.windowProc(Widget.java:2009)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4723)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._gtk_widget_show(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.gtk_widget_show(OS.java:14774)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabFolder.createItem(TabFolder.java:311)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabItem.createWidget(TabItem.java:123)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabItem.<init>(TabItem.java:75)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.publish.wizard.page.DatasourceSelectionPage.createControl(DatasourceSelectionPage.java:69)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard.createPageControls(Wizard.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createPageControls(WizardDialog.java:705)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createContents(WizardDialog.java:597)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:430)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1096)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:792)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.publish.action.JrxmlPublishAction.publishReportUnit(JrxmlPublishAction.java:173)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.publish.action.JrxmlPublishAction$2.run(JrxmlPublishAction.java:104)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UILockListener.doPendingWork(UILockListener.java:162)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer$3.run(UISynchronizer.java:154)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
... 34 more
```

I am using Linux 4.7.2-1-ARCH and Jasper Studio: 6.3.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be connected to the new GTK 3.

Open the corresponding studio *ini* file and add the parameter

```
--launcher.GTK_version 2
```

just before

```
-vm ......
```

[Source](http://www.asesoriaensig.com.mx/blog/?p=1531)